# Are these notions of the convergence of two sided series equivalent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-analysis

From Stein and Shakarchi's text on Fourier analysis, the definition of a convergent Fourier series is when the following sequence of partial sum converges:

Definition 2.2. We define the $N^{t h}$ partial sum of the Fourier series of $f, N \in \mathbb{N}$ by
$$
S_N(f)(x):=\sum_{n=-N}^N \hat{f}(n) e^{2 \pi i n x / L} .
$$

Now Sheldon Axler's measure and integration also has a chapter on what it means for Fourier series to converge using the notion of an unordered series:

Definition: unordered sum: $\sum_{k \in \Gamma} f_k$
Suppose $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k \in \Gamma}$ is a family in a normed vector space $V$. The unordered sum $\sum_{k \in \Gamma} f_k$ is said to converge if there exists $g \in V$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a finite subset $\Omega$ of $\Gamma$ such that
$$
\left\|g-\sum_{j \in \Omega^{\prime}} f_j\right\|<\varepsilon
$$
for all finite sets $\Omega^{\prime}$ with $\Omega \subset \Omega^{\prime} \subset \Gamma$. If this happens, we set $\sum_{k \in \Gamma} f_k=g$. If there is no such $g \in V$, then $\sum_{k \in \Gamma} f_k$ is left undefined.

and he defined the convergence of a Fourier series to be when the unordered sum converges.

I would like to ask if these two notions of convergence are the same as far as Fourier series are concerned?
And what about in general like in the case of $l^1\mathbb(Z)$ which is the space of all summable double-sided sequences of complex numbers?